# How to resize a CTabCtrl to fit its contents

Tags: c++, mfc, ctabctrl

I have a **CTabCtrl** in my program and 3 "child" **CFormView**s that I show/hide whenever the user changes the active tab.

Instead of using a fixed size, I'd like to resize the enclosing CTabCtrl to match the size of the largest CFormView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

GetDlgItem(IDC_YOURCONTROL)->MoveWindow(xPosInScreen, yPosInScreen, Width, Height);

Hope it helps.